# ansible galaxy role's command/module name clashes with built-in runit module

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use an ansible-galaxy (https://github.com/gotansible/runit) role to help with `runit` service monitor.

From their readme, I came up with this as my task:

```
- name: runit gunicorn
  #this command/module(? not sure about term) is provided by gotansible.runit
  runit:
    command: "gunicorn websec.wsgi -c /etc/gunicorn/gunicorn.conf"
    state: up
  tags:
    - failing
```

But when I run the playbook I get:

```
 FAILED! => {"changed": false, 
 "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (runit) module: command 
 Supported parameters include: dist, enabled, name, service_dir, service_src, state"}
```

Which makes sense when you look at the built-in runit module supports https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/runit_module.html

Is there a way to point ansible at `gotansible.runit`'s module, rather than Ansible's built-in module?

Neither

```
- name: runit gunicorn
  gotansible.runit:
```

or

```
- name: runit gunicorn
  gotansible_runit:
```

seemed to help much.

This is just some quick experimentation, I will probably avoid using that role which doesn't look recently maintained anyway.  But I am curious in how name clashes are handled.  https://github.com/ksator/junos-automation-with-ansible/blob/master/README.md for example said they renamed some of their modules to avoid name clashes.

Answer (score 0):

Roles have to called this way

```
hosts: server
roles:
  - { role: gotansible.runit }
```

as explained on the homepage of https://github.com/gotansible/runit.

Should you need to pass parameters to the role, you do this way

```
hosts: server
roles:
  - { role: gotansible.runit, state: once, name: foo }
```

When you have

```
- runit:
    name: foo
    state: started
```

You are colling the [runit](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/runit_module.html) builtin module

more information on roles on https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html

Comment: I know, but `runit:` is actually a module provided in the role, which you can use within a task.  my `roles:` declaration looks just like yours.

Comment: No, `runit` IS NOT provided by the role. the only way to use the role is the way I wrote. If you call `runit` you are calling the builtin `runit` module

Comment: i know i am calling the builtin module.  but look at the role's documentation.  besides installing runit, it also provides a module/command that can be used in a task.  it's in an example of theirs.  but it predates the arrival of the builtin